# Cross browser/cross platform offline phone app

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, jaydata

We have a new build requirement that needs to work as follows:

- the functionality of the App is that the maintains data related to tasks assigned to the User
- the App needs takes data in the form of XML via WebAPI, the XML is a list of tasks for the User has been assigned. This would be a task bundle
- once the XML is downloaded the User can work offline, i.e. they need to be able to maintain data related to their tasks, the data needs to persist on the phone, tasks would be completed over time in different sessions
- there can be a number of current taks bundles "on the device" for the User
- when online the App can submit an XML back up to the server, the purpose of this is to communicate the data entered by the user for the task bundle

If this was an online app it would be fairly straightforward, the data resides on the server. I have done a lot of research on the web with regard to the best way to build the app to satisfy the requirement that the App works on all browsers and platforms.

We're thinking of going with HTML5 & JayData. Haven't made any firm and final decisions, so would welcome any suggestions and constructive comment.

Answer (score 0):

I work for JayData. If you have concerns against JayData just let us know and we'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this article will help you to start your online/offline app - [How to create a synchronized Online/Offline data application with EntityFramework, JavaScript and JayData](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-create-a-synchronized-online-offline-data-application-with-javascript-and-jaydata)